# Python Subprocess Behavior with Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I am trying to run Eclipse from the command line to automate some project importing and i am having an issue with pythons subprocess. Subprocess seems to be ignoring my command arguments and just running eclipse straight up.

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
subprocess.call(["C:/eclipse/eclipsec",
                 "-nosplash",
                 "--launcher.suppressErrors",
                 "-application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild",
                 "-data", workspace_dir,
                 "-import", project_dir])
```

But when i run this Eclipse just opens and doesn't perform the import. However if i change the command to:

```
subprocess.call(['eclipse_import.bat', workspace_dir, project_dir)])
```

Where `eclipse_import.bat` is:

```
set workspace_dir=%1
set project_dir=%2

C:/eclipse/eclipsec -nosplash --launcher.suppressErrors -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data %workspace_dir% -import %project_dir%
```

Then everything behaves exactly as i expect it to.

Any ideas as to what would cause the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way you're calling it *should* work properly, and I don't know why it isn't. Perhaps Eclipse is trying to accept arguments in an odd way that your batch script handles correctly but `subprocess.call()` doesn't, but that's entirely conjecture on my part.

As a alternative, you can try calling it with the `shell=True` argument and make your argument list a string instead:

```
call_string = "C:/eclipse/eclipsec -nosplash --launcher.suppressErrors -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data {} -import {}".format(workspace_dir, project_dir))

subprocess.call(call_string, shell=True)
```

This will cause your default shell to parse the arguments instead of doing it natively in Python, which is very similar to your batch script workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I'm suppose the problem is `"-application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild"` list element. You should split it in

```
"-application","org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild"
```

A way to see how you must split the line is use `shlex` module:

```
import shlex
shlex.split('C:/eclipse/eclipsec -nosplash --launcher.suppressErrors -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data workr_dir -import project_dir')
```

and prit it give to you the arguments list for `call` or `Popen()`

```
['C:/eclipse/eclipsec', '-nosplash', '--launcher.suppressErrors', '-application', 'org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild', '-data', 'workr_dir', '-import', 'project_dir']
```

Comment: I marked the other answer as the official answer, but your solution worked as well